# Using GLES 2 shader to hide overlapping pixels

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

Is there a way to hide overlapping pixels using shaders in GLES 2? I am using the following vertex and fragment shader.

### Vertex Shader:

```c
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main (void)
{
    v_color     = a_color;
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

### Fragment Shader:

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp
precision mediump float;
#else
#define LOWP 
#endif

varying vec2      v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main (void)
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to check to see if the position has a filled in pixel or not. If it does then skip the position else draw from the texture. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you considered using a depth test for that purpose? :) That's what it was designed for.

Comment: No, I am new to shaders in general. I will read up on that and see what it is about. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have thought about it, I think you could do it in one pass using Stencil.
I have never done this myself so I am not sure but it could work.

You need to set the stencil op to:

```
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_ZERO)
```

This will make the stencil test zero the stencil value in a pixel in case the depth and stencil test has passed, and do nothing in case it didn't.

And the stencil func to:

```
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

This will make the stencil test pass if the stencil value is 1.

Before you render your mesh/scene, you need to clear your stencil buffer and set all it's pixels into the value of 0x00000001.
What this will cause is that every time you render a pixel it will test if the stencil value in that pixel is 1. If it is indeed 1 it will render the pixel and zero the stencil value.
The next time there is an attempt to draw a pixel into the same place, the stencil value will be 0 and the stencil test will fail, thus your pixel won't be drawn.

This is one way I can think of pulling this off.

Hope this helps you.